# MYSQL - number of rows returned vs number of connections?

Tags: mysql

Does my query get sent to the database once and I get a list of all the results in one shot which I then loop through, or do I have to request the next row from the DB each time?

Essentially, does reducing the number of rows I expect to return mean less connections/calls to the DB meaning my DB will be able to handle more connections at once, or is the number of database connections not dependent on the number of returned rows?

Comment: Most database APIs have a "connect" call, which opens a connection to the database, and then everything happens on that same connection.

Comment: If you're using an OO API like PDO, each instance of the database class corresponds to a database connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very vague, and seems to have the terminology jumbled up.

The number of rows retrieved from a resultset has no bearing on the number of connections. Nor does the number of statements executed have any bearing on connections.

(Unless it's a very badly written application that churns connections, connecting and disconnecting from the database for each statement execution.)

---

I think what you're asking is whether there's a "roundtrip" made to the database server for each "fetch", to retrieve a row from a resultset returned by a SELECT query.

The answer to that question is no, most database libraries fetch a "batch" of rows. When the client requests the next row, it's returned from the set already returned by the library. Once the batch is exhausted, it's another roundtrip to get the next set. That's all "under the covers" and your application doesn't need to worry about it.

It doesn't matter whether you fetch just one row, and then discard the resultset, or whether you loo[ through and fetch every row. It's the same pattern.

In terms of performance and scalability, if you only need to retrieve four rows, then there's no sense in preparing a resultset containing more than that. When your query runs against the database, the database server generates the resultset, and holds that, until the client requests a row from the resultset. Larger resultsets require more resources on the database server.

A huge resultset is going to need more roundtrips to the database server, to retrieve all of the rows, than a smaller resultset.

It's not just the number of rows, it's also the size of the row being returned. (Which is why DBA types gripe about developer queries that do a `SELECT * FROM` query to retrieve every flipping column, when the client is actually using only a small subset of the columns.)

Reducing roundtrips to the database generally improves performance, especially if the client is connecting to the database server over a network connection.

But we don't really need to be concerned how many roundtrips it requires to fetch all the rows from a resultset... it takes what it takes, the client needs what it needs.

What we should be concerned with is the number of queries we run

A query execution is WAY more overhead than the simple roundtrip for a fetch. The SQL statement has to be parsed for syntax (order and pattern of keywords and identifiers is correct), for semantics (the identifiers reference valid tables, columns, functions, and user has to appropriate permissions on the database objects), generate a execution plan (evaluate which predicates and operations can be satisfied with which indexes, the permutations for the order the operations are performed in). Finally, the statement can be executed, and if a resultset is being returned, prepare that, and then notify the client of query completion status, and wait for the client to request rows from the resultset, when the client closes the resultset, the database server can clean up, releasing the memory, etc.

Answer (score 0):

These aren't linked. The number of connections you are able to make is based on the quality of the thread library and the amount of RAM available / used by each thread. So essentially, it is limited by the quality of the systems and not the complexity of the database. As the threads use a buffer, the number of rows will only make the processes slower or a fixed amount of RAM. see here for more 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-use.html

Answer (score 0):

Q: Does my query get sent to the database once and I get a list of all the results in one shot which I then loop through, or do I have to request the next row from the DB each time?

A: You are getting back the batch of rows. You are iterating thru until you need the next batch (trip to DB on the same connection). Size of batch depends on multiple conditions, if your query result dataset is small you may get all results in one shot.

Q: Essentially, does reducing the number of rows I expect to return mean less connections/calls to the DB meaning my DB will be able to handle more connections at once, or is the number of database connections not dependent on the number of returned rows?

A: The larger the dataset the more trips (to grab next set of rows) to DB there may be. But number of connections opened to DB does not depend on your result dataset size for single query.